# Bamboo - Pass Environmental Variables Between Tasks/Scripts

Tags: shell, bamboo

Is it possible to pass environment variables set in one script to another in Bamboo?

For example, I set up Go as below, and would like subsequent Tasks (scripts) to have access to the PATH and GOPATH I export here.

```
set -e

if [ ! -d "go" ]; then
    wget -q https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    tar -xzf go1.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
fi

export GOROOT=$(pwd)/go

mkdir -p gopath/
export GOPATH=$(pwd)/gopath
export PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 10):

This has been implemented using the `Inject Variables` plugin, which is bundled since 5.7:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-variable-inject-plugin/server/overview

The way to do it is the following:

- in an initial task, have a script store the state to a file (in `key=value` format), something like:

> echo "MYVAR=$(cat some_variable_info_file)" >> build/docker.properties

- configure a following `Inject` task to read the properties file from the previous step into Bamboo variables. Set the PATH to the properties file (e.g. **build/docker.properties**) and set a namespace, say **docker**
- to use this variable in the next script task*, one can refer to it as:
  **$bamboo_docker_MYVAR** where `docker` is the namespace and `MYVAR` is the key of the property in the property file. It can be referred to, for example, as:

> echo $bamboo_docker_MYVAR

This means you can still used the file-based approach, just make sure the data in there is of type:

```
some_key1=some_value1
some_key2=some_value2
```

etc.

**Note that from the Bamboo documentation, the underscores are the way to use it:*
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-variables-289277087.html

**Using variables in bash**

Bamboo variables are exported as bash shell variables. All full stops (periods) are converted to underscores. For example, the variable bamboo.my.variable is $bamboo_my_variable in bash. This is related to File Script tasks (not Inline Script tasks).

Comment: It's sad that five year later, wet still have to do this in Bamboo.

Answer (score 4):

Environment variables can only be passed from parent to child processes.
To get them into an unrelated program, you could write them into a file, and then source the file in the other script:

```
...
echo export GOROOT=$GOROOT >>$GOROOT/.vars
echo export GOPATH=$GOPATH >>$GOROOT/.vars
echo export PATH=$PATH >>$GOROOT/.vars
```

Then other scripts which start later on, should have this near the beginning (assuming they start with their working directory in the GOROOT directory):

```
source .vars
```

(Or add it in the script that starts those other scripts.)

Comment: Hello Guys, Is this is the only way available till now ?, As i was seeking a way to send the result of one task to the next task but not able to find any default way provided by Bamboo. Can someone who have achieved this successful can elaborate on this....in context to the latest version of Bamboo CI Server. Any help would be appreciated. Thnx